# Ajax Get Syntax

Tags: php, ajax, http, get, request

I 've read few tutorials about ajax http request, but somehow i couldn't understand it enough to build a syntax i need.

```
var path = $(this).data('path');
    $.get('http://example.ro/index.php?page=contract.php&path='+path, function(){

    });
```

What i try to achieve is to change url (http://example.ro/index.php?page=contract.php) , without reloading the page,so i can use the path value for later use in a query or some other action,in the same page.But the url doesnt change (it must be with &path=value at the end),so i can't catch the value with something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
/do something
}
```

Is the syntax wrong? or i cant do it in this way? Help please!

**UPDATE**

$(document).on('click','tr.listContractRow', function(e){

```
   var path = $(this).data('path');
    $.ajax({
  type: 'get',
    url: 'contract.php',
    data: {id: path},
    success: function(result) {
   
      console.log(result)
    },
    error: function() {
      
    }
});


});
```

The variable path is a value taken from a php content,and i want to take it with ajax and return it back so i can catch it with php.

Comment: Your question is very confused. What do you need to do other than setup an ajax call? Where path is stored? on a form? on a variable?

Comment: path is taken from a php table , but that is not the point.I just need to know if that syntax is right,because it does nothing....

Comment: You have 2 negative votes on the question, and i did not put any. You should really explain better if you ask for help. I answered with the correct ajax syntax from jquery.

Comment: I think you want `ajax`, not `get`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Right syntax for an ajax get request made with jquery:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'get',
        url: 'yourphpscript.php',
        data: {
          key1: value1,
          keyn: valuen
        },
        success: function(result) {
          // to be executed on status 200 OK
          console.log(result) // to check what you sent back from your page
        },
        error: function() {
          //to be executed on status 500 error
        }
    });
```

this is a pretty basic syntax.

Let's assume you are on your page.
And you want to call an ajax request, get something from it, store in your page, and send it back later to another php. with a submit or with another ajax.

So step1:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'get',
        url: 'givemepath.php',
        data: {
          key1: value1,
          keyn: valuen
        },
        success: function(result) {
          // pretty ugly, but functional.
          window.path = result.path;
          // or if you plan to submit a form prepare an hidden field with id myhiddenfield
          $.('#myhiddenfield').val(result.path);
        },
        error: function() {
          //to be executed on status 500 error
        }
    });
```

your givemepath.php

```
<?php
  $path = ...some php code....
  header("content-Type: application/json");
  echo json_encode(array("path" => $path));
?>
```

Later when you want to use again this value in your page

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'get',
        url: 'sendpathbacklater.php',
        data: {
          path: window.path,
          otherdata: otherdata
        },
        success: function(result) {
          //sent it!
        },
        error: function() {
          //to be executed on status 500 error
        }
    });
```

or just submit your form.

Comment: ok so what i dont understand is this : how to return the value to the same page so i can catch there with php ??

Comment: I believe my problem is with succes: function(result){} .I think i must put there a code to return the value to a file....